# 70s/80s science fantasy book series set on vast grassy plain - anyone recall title?

Tags: story-identification

Trying to recall author and title of a series written 70s/80s or possibly even earlier?? only memory is of plot is that the stories were set on world? that was a vast dangerous grassy plain and that one of the central characters in the story 'grew' himself a new body in his 'lab'? Anyone have an idea of this series??

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. I recommend a look at our [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) to story id questions, which might help you remember more details to help guide someone to the right answer.

Comment: It could maybe be Jack Chalker's "Well World" series (starting with "Midnight at the Well of Sould". One of the millieus on Well World is a grassy plain inhabited by centaurs, and one of the characters, Nathan Brazil, turns out to have some ancient affiliation to the Well World and maybe grows himself a new body. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_World_series

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like something by PJ Farmer. Could it be World of Tiers/Makers of universes?

Desolate natural environments, biotechnology, and immortality are recurring elements in Farmer's oeuvre. I suggested *World of Tiers* because

- one of the tiers is a vast plain inhabited by centaurs,
- the protagonist is one of a family of immortals highly skilled in biotechnology, and
- Chrysalis, the protagonist's lover, gets cloned.

Comment: The lover's name was Chryseis if memory serves and the 'lord' of the pocket universe was Jadawin, also known as Wolff. I don't remember any of the protagonists growing a new body though for themselves although the creatures populating the worlds were grown in labs by the 'lords', an advanced but fallen race who had largely forgotten how their technology works but remember how to use it.

Comment: The hero in the first book enters the World of Tiers as an old man, but his body turns young (slowly, or all at once; can't remember) when he gets there. So it could be said that he grows a new body.

Comment: As KAM says, Wolff enters the World of Tiers from Earth as an old man, the youth/immortality drugs in the environment there rejuvenate him and eventually he recalls his past life as Jadawin. Kickaha, also an earthman, helps him recover his position as lord of the world of tiers and later becomes the lover of Anana (Jadawin's sister). Read the first three books to death many years ago. Not so impressed by the later books though.